# Prove that there exists $A \in F$ (σ-algebra) such that $P(A) = a$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**The question**

Let $\left( \Omega,F,P \right)$ be a probability space.

A set $E\in F $ is called  **K-set** iff

$P(E)>0$ and $B \subseteq E$ with $B \in F$ $\Rightarrow P(B) = P(E)$ **or** $P(B) = 0$

**Note**: I don't know how the above term is translated in English. I looked it up on Google but found nothing so I will name it for the sake of this post as **K-set**. If anyone knows the name of this term please tell me.

Suppose that the probability measure $P$ has no $K$-sets. Prove that for every $a \in [0,1]$ there exists $A \in F$ such that $P(A) = a$

**Attempt**

So $P$ has not $K$-sets. From this I understand that

$\forall A \in F$ with $P(A)>0$ and $\forall B \subseteq A$ with $B \in F$ we have $P(B) \neq P(A)$ **and** $P(B)>0$

For $a=0$, $P(\emptyset ) = 0$ and $\emptyset \in F$ since $F$ is $\sigma$-algebra.

For $a=1$, $P(\Omega) = 1$ and $\Omega \in F$ since $F$ is $\sigma$-algebra.

For $a \in (0,1)$ I thought of the idea that we can find a sequence $\{B_{n} \}$ of sets in $A$ such that $B_{n+1} \subset B_{n} \forall n $

I also tried using the Borel-Cantelli Theorem and other Propositions involving $\lim \inf B_n $ and $\lim \sup B_n $ but couldn't get to the desired result. I know that $P(B_n)$ will get smaller and smaller as $n$ gets bigger. But how do I know that $\forall a \in (0,1)$ I can find such $B_n$ such that $P(B_n) =a$ ? If this is the approach anyway.

Comment: Sometimes such a set is called an "atom" for the measure $P$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I think K is coming from 'Kolmogorov'.

Comment: @Berci I don't know about that. I made up this name for the sake of this post. It may be true though.

Comment: Ah, I thought that's from the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

In the following, unless otherwise specified, all sets under
consideration are measurable. That is, if we say "let $A\subseteq\Omega$"
we actually mean $A\in\mathcal{F}$.

---

Lemma 1:
Assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ does not have $K$-set, then we have: For any $A\subseteq\Omega$ with
$P(A)>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $B\subseteq A$ such
that $0<P(B)<\varepsilon$.

Proof of Lemma 1: Let $A\subseteq\Omega$ with $P(A)>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$
be given. Choose $B_{0}\subseteq A$ such that $0<P(B_{0})<P(A)$.
Define $A_{1}=\begin{cases}
B_{0}, & \mbox{if }P(B_{0})\leq\frac{1}{2}P(A)\\
A\setminus B_{0}, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$ Note that $0<P(A_{1})\leq\frac{1}{2}P(A).$ Suppose that $A\supseteq A_{1}\supseteq\ldots\supseteq A_{n}$
have been chosen. Choose $B_{n}\subseteq A_{n}$ such that $0<P(B_{n})<P(A_{n}).$
Define $A_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
B_{n}, & \mbox{if }P(B_{n})\leq\frac{1}{2}P(A_{n})\\
A_{n}\setminus B_{n}, & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$ Clearly $0<P(A_{n+1})\leq\frac{1}{2}P(A_{n})$ and hence $P(A_{n})\rightarrow0.$
In particular, for sufficiently large $n$, $0<P(A_{n})<\varepsilon$.

---

We go back to your question. Let $a\in[0,1]$ be given. If $a=0$
or $a=1$, we may choose $A=\emptyset$ or $A=\Omega$ respectively.
Suppose that $a\in(0,1).$ Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on
$\mathcal{F}$ by $A\sim B$ iff $P(A\Delta B)=0$, where $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.
Intuitively, $A\sim B$ means that $A=B$ modulo a $P$-null set.
If $A\in\mathcal{F}$, we denote the equivalence class containing $A$
by $\tilde{A}$. Note that if $B\in\tilde{A}$, then $P(B)=P(A)$,
so it is well-defined to specify $P(\tilde{A})=P(A)$. Define a binary
relation on $\mathcal{F}/\sim$ by $\tilde{A}\preceq\tilde{B}$ iff
$P(A\setminus B)=0$. It is routine to verify that $\preceq$ is well-defined
(i.e., if $A_{1},A_{2}\in\tilde{A}$ and $B_{1},B_{2}\in\tilde{B}$,
then $P(A_{1}\setminus B_{1})=0$ iff $P(A_{2}\setminus B_{2})=0$).
Moreover, $\preceq$ is a partial ordering on $\mathcal{F}/\sim$.
Intuitively, $\tilde{A}\preceq \tilde{B}$ means that $A\subseteq B$ modulo a $P$-null set.

Let $\mathcal{C}=\{\tilde{A}\in\mathcal{F}/\sim\,\,\,\mid\,\,\, P(\tilde{A})\leq a\}$.
Clearly $\mathcal{C}$ is non-empty. We go to show that $\mathcal{C}$
contains a $\preceq$-maximal element. Let $\mathcal{C}_{1}=\{\tilde{A}_{i}\mid i\in I\}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$
be a chain, where $I$ is an index set. Let $b=\sup_{i\in I}P(\tilde{A}_{i})$.
Note that $b\leq a$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $i_{n}\in I$
such that $P(\tilde{A}_{i_{n}})>b-\frac{1}{n}.$ Define $B_{n}=\cup_{k=1}^{n}A_{i_{k}}$.
Since $\mathcal{C}_{1}$ is a chain, we can prove by induction that
$B_{n}\sim A_{i_{k}}$ for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Therefore $b\geq P(B_{n})\geq P(A_{i_{n}})>b-\frac{1}{n}$. Let $B=\cup_{n}B_{n}$.
By continuity of measure, we have $P(B)=b\leq a$, so $\tilde{B}\in\mathcal{C}$.
We assert that $\tilde{B}$ is an upper bound of the chain $\mathcal{C}_{1}$.
Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exists $j\in I$
such that $P(A_{j}\setminus B)>0$. Choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such
that $P(A_{j}\setminus B)>\frac{1}{n}$. Since $\mathcal{C}_{1}$
is a chain, we have $\tilde{A}_{j}\preceq \tilde{A}_{i_{n}}$ or $\tilde{A}_{i_{n}}\preceq \tilde{A}_{j}$.
If $\tilde{A}_{j}\preceq \tilde{A}_{i_{n}}$, then $P(A_{j}\setminus B)\leq P(A_{i_{n}}\setminus B)=0$
which is a contradiction. If $\tilde{A}_{i_{n}}\preceq \tilde{A}_{j}$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
b & \geq & P(A_{j})\\
 & = & P(A_{j}\setminus B)+P(A_{j}\cap B)\\
 & > & \frac{1}{n}+P(A_{i_{n}}\cap B)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{n}+P(A_{i_{n}})\\
 & > & \frac{1}{n}+(b-\frac{1}{n})
\end{eqnarray*}
which is also a contradiction. By Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal{C}$ contains
a maximal element $\tilde{A}$.

We go to show that $P(\tilde{A})=a$ by contradiction, then it will follow that $P(A)=a$. Suppose the
contrary that $P(\tilde{A})<a$. Choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$P(\tilde{A})+\varepsilon<a$. Clearly $P(A^{c})>0$. By Lemma 1,
we can choose $B\subseteq A^{c}$ such that $0<P(B)<\varepsilon$.
Now $P(\widetilde{A\cup B})=P(A)+P(B)<P(A)+\varepsilon<a$. Therefore
$\widetilde{A\cup B}\in\mathcal{C}$. Clearly $\tilde{A}\preceq\widetilde{A\cup B}$,
so $\tilde{A}=\widetilde{A\cup B}$ by maximality of $\tilde{A}$.
However, $P(A\Delta(A\cup B))=P(B)>0$, contradicting to $A\sim A\cup B$.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and I thank you for this. However,  a lot of information mentioned above has not been taught yet and I suppose I am to solve this exercise using information taught up to the current point. All that is currently available is propositions involving $\lim \inf A_n$,$\lim \sup A_n$, ,$P(\lim \sup A_n)$ and $P()$ of the union and intersection of countably infinite sets $A_n$. Do you think it is possible to solve this problem using only this information?

Answer (score 0):

For any $E\in F$ with $P(E)>0$ we can construct $E\supset E_1\supset E_2\supset\dots$ such that $P(E_n)\to 0$.
Taking their relative complements, we get $E'_n:=E\setminus E_n$ such that $P(E'_n)\to P(E)$.

Apply this construction first for $E=X$ to find $A_1:=E_n$ where $n$ is the smallest index with $P(E_n)\le a$.
Then apply it for $E=X\setminus A_1$ and define $B_1:=A_1\cup E'_m$ where $m$ is the smallest index with $P(E'_m)\ge a-P(A_1)$,
so that $A_1\subset B_1$ and $P(A_1)\le a\le P(B_1)$.

Repeat this procedure for $E=E'_m$ to construct the required sequence $A_i$.

Comment: Yes this is the idea I mentioned at the end of the post. Since lim inf En = lim sup En then lim En = E' and using Propositions we have that P(En) -> 0. But how can this help with finding a set B such that P(B) = a? Edit: For example 1/n -> 0 but we cannot find n in naturals such that 1/n = 1/3.5

Comment: Ah ok. I will update my answer. First let $E=X$ and pick $E_i$ with smallest index such that $P(E_i)\le a$ then continue with $E\setminus E_i$ as $E$ and $a-P(E_i)$.

Comment: I am sorry but I still cannot figure it out. So yes, there is a smallest index $n_0$ such that $ 0< P(E_{n}) \leq a \forall n \geq n_{0} $ (I am not sure about the equal part though). Then for $Y = X \setminus E_{n_0}$, $Y \in F$ and $P(Y) >0$, we have $G \subseteq Y$ and we can find $m_0  \forall n \geq n_0  $ such that $ 0<P(G_{m}) \leq a - P(E_{n_{0}}) \forall m \geq m_0 $.  How does that help? For $n \to \infty$ we will have $ 0<P(G_{m}) \leq a$ for some m and above.